# querySelectorAll - get ALL tags that have an attribute set?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

For example, I need to have a list of all tags that have `id` attribute set (it could be any other attribute, `id` is just an example).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id]')
```